# loading a no javascript version of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a webpage that requires very little javascript. Although I still need to make the site work for all users. So first I ask, is there a way to hid a single div when javascript is disabled. If this is not possible how would I go about loading a different version of the page that doesn't have the div in it

Comment: try hiding the div by default then write a line of javascript to unhide the div.  If they viewer doesn't have javascript enabled it'll be hidden.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! I was able to load the div in jquery for the Javascript version.

Answer (score 3):

Use the noscript tag
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

```
<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```